# Merge Map<String, List<String> Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I would like to merge two Map with JAVA 8 Stream:

```
Map<String, List<String>> mapGlobal = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
Map<String, List<String>> mapAdded = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

I try to use this implementation:

```
mapGlobal = Stream.of(mapGlobal, mapAdded)
                .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,        
                                           Collectors.toList())
                ));
```

However, this implementation only create a result like:

`Map<String, List<Object>>`

If one key is not contained in the `mapGlobal`, it would be added as a new key with the corresponding List of String. If the key is duplicated in `mapGlobal` and `mapAdded`, both list of values will be merge as: `A = {1, 3, 5, 7}` and `B = {1, 2, 4, 6}` then `A ∪ B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this by iterating over all the entries in `mapAdded` and merging them into `mapGlobal`.

The following iterates over the entries of `mapAdded` by calling [`forEach(action)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) where the action consumes the key and value of each entry. For each entry, we call [`merge(key, value, remappingFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) on `mapGlobal`: this will either create the entry under the key `k` and value `v` if the key didn't exist or it will invoke the given remapping function if they already existed. This function takes the 2 lists to merge, which in this case, are first added to a `TreeSet` to ensure both unique and sorted elements and converted back into a list:

```
mapAdded.forEach((k, v) -> mapGlobal.merge(k, v, (v1, v2) -> {
    Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>(v1);
    set.addAll(v2);
    return new ArrayList<>(set);
}));
```

If you want to run that potentially in parallel, you can create a Stream pipeline by getting the `entrySet()` and calling `parallelStream()` on it. But then, you need to make sure to use a map that supports concurrency for `mapGlobal`, like a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

```
ConcurrentMap<String, List<String>> mapGlobal = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
// ...
mapAdded.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach(e -> mapGlobal.merge(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), (v1, v2) -> {
    Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>(v1);
    set.addAll(v2);
    return new ArrayList<>(set);
}));
```

Comment: this implementation will not use the improvements in the stream collections. Both maps can be huge then I would like to use something like parallelStream(). Is that possible.

Comment: Unless `mapGlobal` is a `ConcurrentMap`, mutating it from inside a parallel stream is not safe.

Comment: @Misha Correct, hence the suggested use of a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: @Tunaki Well, -1 to me for reading comprehension.  I apologize.

Comment: @Misha I understand :) and made an edit to make it clearer.

Answer (score 5):

Using foreach over Map can be used to merge given arraylist.

```
    public Map<String, ArrayList<String>> merge(Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map1, Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map2) {
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.putAll(map1);

    map2.forEach((key , value) -> {
        //Get the value for key in map.
        ArrayList<String> list = map.get(key);
        if (list == null) {
            map.put(key,value);
        }
        else {
            //Merge two list together
            ArrayList<String> mergedValue = new ArrayList<>(value);
            mergedValue.addAll(list);
            map.put(key , mergedValue);
        }
    });
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The original implementation doesn't create result like `Map<String, List<Object>>`, but `Map<String, List<List<String>>>`. You need additional Stream pipeline on it to produce `Map<String, List<String>>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry: map1.entrySet()) {
   result.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>(entry.getValue());
}

for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry: map2.entrySet()) {
   if(result.contains(entry.getKey())){
       result.get(entry.getKey()).addAll(entry.getValue());
   } else {
       result.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>(entry.getValue());
   }

}
```

This solution creates independent result map without any reference to map1 and map2 lists.

Answer (score 0):

Using [StreamEx](https://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/package-summary.html)

```
Map<String, List<String>> mergedMap =
        EntryStream.of(mapGlobal)
                .append(EntryStream.of(mapAdded))
                .toMap((v1, v2) -> {
                    List<String> combined = new ArrayList<>();
                    combined.addAll(v1);
                    combined.addAll(v2);
                    return combined;
                });
```

If you have even more maps to merge just append to the stream

```
                .append(EntryStream.of(mapAdded2))
                .append(EntryStream.of(mapAdded3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code to Iterate Two HashMap which has values stored in the form of a list. Merging all the keys and values in first hashmap. Below is the example.

```java
HashMap<String, List<String>> hmap1 = new HashMap<>();
      List<String> list1 = new LinkedList<>();
      list1.add("000");
      list1.add("111");
      List<String> list2 = new LinkedList<>();
      list2.add("222");
      list2.add("333");
      hmap1.put("Competitor", list1);
      hmap1.put("Contractor", list2);
      //  System.out.println(hmap1);


      HashMap<String, List<String>> hmap2 = new HashMap<>();
      List<String> list3 = new LinkedList<>();
      list3.add("aaa");
      list3.add("bbb");
      List<String> list4 = new LinkedList<>();
      list4.add("ccc");
      list4.add("ddd");
      hmap2.put("Competitor", list3);
      hmap2.put("Contractor", list4);


//******* Java 8 Feature *****
hmap1.forEach((k, v) -> hmap2.merge(k, v, (v1, v2) -> {
          List<String> li = new LinkedList<>(v1);
          li.addAll(v2);
          hmap2.put(k,li);
          return new ArrayList<>(li);
      }));
      System.out.println(hmap2);
```

Output:

```
{Competitor=[aaa, bbb, 000, 111], Contractor=[ccc, ddd, 222, 333]}
```